# Android service for listening for network connections

Tags: android

As the title says, I'm wondering if the there is some way in Android for listen to network connections. Something like using a service that is registered to handle the SMS messages that, for example, we can consume the SMS and broadcast or not that SMS.

The idea is that my app will sit on the background and be notified when some app makes a network connection. Based on some rules, my app can decide if this network connection will be denied or allowed.

As an example, suppose an app tries to connect to the Wireless network with SSID "netA". My app would be notified and if the rule is to deny this app on "netA" the calling app would not be able to connect to the network.

Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a Broadcast recevier that listen for some events?.
It seems to me from your description that you don't need a Service, that is a android component that runs long time task, but something that listens to events.
Give a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know how to do. Thought of a service. Didn't know that the Broadcast Receiver would be able to be notified if an app tries to make a network connection.

Comment: I've read a bunch of docs and I can be notified if the network is enabled or not, if the connectivity changed but I did not find how to be notified or how to check if another app (not mine) is making a network request and if so, block it before any data being transferred. Any idea on this?